# SSRS 2016 Toolbar Back Button

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am trying to figure out in SSRS 2016 why the back button goes missing and how to get it back.  I am adding the report into an iFrame of another application - I do not have access to that application's code, I just get to put in a URL.

If I put in a URL like this:
http://sqlservername/Reports/report/Cityworks%20Reports/Parks/ParksReport?rs:embed=true

I get the back button, however the report does not scroll horizontally very well.
[image]

If I put the URL in like this, the report scrolls horizontally very well however the back button goes missing:
http://sqlservername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?Cityworks+Reports%2fParks%2fParksReport&rs:Command=Render

[image]

I have tried to see what other options are available and am stumped at the moment.  Has anyone come across this and know a solution?

Comment: I entered into the same problem, Maybe you found any solution except for add internal back button inside any relevant report? Thank you!

Comment: You know, I do not think we did find a solution but I forget now!  I apologize for that and I no longer have access to the application as I switched employers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add to the wanted URL the follow parameter

```
&rc:showbackbutton=true
```

Comment: Ooh, yes that does look familiar, I think we may have tried that with success.

Comment: really, it works perfect as desired, you can mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

One URL is for the Report manager, and the other for Browsing. The URL with YourServer\ReportServer is the browser landing page; there's therefore no "need" for the back button as it's purely a browsing page. If you go to http://YourServerName/ReportServer you'll see you have a page that very much looks like one you get with IIS with folder browsing enabled. Normally you only land on these pages when you receive a report by email, which contains a link to the report; or you are an end user.

The other URL YourServer\Reports is the report manager. It makes more sense here to have a back button, as you are navigating a management portal. As a result you could have come from other pages other than the folder browser page.

Comment: I hear you and I agree one way uses the report manager and the other the report service.  The report service view has added to it the aspx page which renders the report.  It shows as the picture you see it, I am stumped as to why this way removes the back button -- to my brain that back button knows we just clicked into a subreport and now we want to go back to the main report.  :) You may be right, though, maybe that was their thinking too.